# Unintended scaling of a polygon

Tags: pgfplots

I want to shadow a polygon with corners at (0,0), (10,5), (10,10) and (5,10) in a plot that has x and y both range between 0 and 10 and, to that end, I used the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ 
     axis x line=bottom,
     axis y line=left,
     ticks=none,
     xmin=0,xmax=10,
     ymin=0,ymax=10,
     ]
     \addplot[draw=none,fill=gray!30!white] (0,0) -- (10,5) -- (10,10) -- (5,10) -- cycle;
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The resulting figure is

[image]

and, although the polygon has its intended shape, it's much smaller than I expected. It is as if it somehow got scaled down. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1) `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, so there is no need to load it separately; 2) add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` to your preamble to ensure that coordinates are interpreted as axis units.

Comment: Write \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4], for example, so 10cm become 4 cm. If I well understand Your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` (or some other sufficiently new version number) to the preamble of your document. You should actually get a warning if you don't set `compat` saying that you are "running in backwards compatibility mode".

What does this mean in this concrete case? In older versions of PGFPlots, coordinates in regular `\path` constructions used a different coordinate system than the the `axis` environment, except if you explicitly added `axis cs:` in front of the relevant coordinate (such as `(axis cs:10,10)`). Today, if you don't state a sufficiently new version via the `compat` option, this behaviour will be retained for compatibility reasons. In newer versions of PGFPlots, you don't need to state `axis cs`, but you need to set `compat` for this. To learn more about this, look for `axis cs` and `compat` in the manual or on this site.

Your code will work as expected with this additional line (note that `pgfplots` already loads `tikz`, so there is no need to load it separately):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[ 
     axis x line=bottom,
     axis y line=left,
     ticks=none,
     xmin=0, xmax=10,
     ymin=0, ymax=10,
   ]
     \addplot[draw=none, fill=gray!30] (0,0) -- (10,5) -- (10,10) -- (5,10) -- cycle;
   \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]